# Draw a tree with tikzpicture, node collapsed problem

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm trying to draw a data structure like the tree with `tikzpicture` but some nodes is collapsed and I'm not able to understand why.

Can you help me to understand why?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{bplus}=[rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split ignore empty parts,draw]
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[bplus]
        \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=70mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=30mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=30mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 4}=[sibling distance=30mm]
        \node[rectangle split parts=10] {2 \nodepart{two} 4 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 1 \nodepart{five} 6 
        \nodepart{six} 7 \nodepart{seven} 8 \nodepart{eight} 9 \nodepart{nine} 1 \nodepart{ten} 7} [->]
        child {node[rectangle split parts=5] {2 \nodepart{two} 4 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 1 \nodepart{five} 6 }
            child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {2 \nodepart{two} 4}}
            child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {3 \nodepart{two} 1 \nodepart{three} 6}}
        } 
        child {node[rectangle split parts=6] {6 \nodepart{two} 7 \nodepart{three} 8 \nodepart{four} 9 \nodepart{five} 1 \nodepart{six} 7}
            child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {6 \nodepart{two} 7 \nodepart{three} 8}
            child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {6}}
            child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {7 \nodepart{two} 8}
                child{node {7}}
                child{node {8}}
            }
            }
            child[sibling distance=25mm] {node {9 \nodepart{two} 1 \nodepart{three} 7}
                child{node {9}}
                child{node {1 \nodepart{two} 7}
                    child{node {1}}
                    child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {7}}
                }
            }
        }
        ;\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could simply adjust the sibling distance wherever there is an overlap  -- please see the answer below if it suits the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `forest` you not need to care for sibling distances:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=10,
    rectangle split ignore empty parts,
    draw,
    %
    parent anchor=south,
    child  anchor=north,
    calign=edge midpoint,
    edge = {-Stealth, semithick},
    l sep=6mm,
    where level=0{s sep=11mm}{s sep=3mm},
            }
[4\nodepart{two} 2 \nodepart{two}   4 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 1 \nodepart{five} 6
  \nodepart{six} 7 \nodepart{seven} 8 \nodepart{eight} 9 \nodepart{nine} 1 \nodepart{ten}  7
    [2\nodepart{two} 2 \nodepart{two} 4 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 1 \nodepart{five} 6
       [2\nodepart{two} 4]
       [3\nodepart{two} 1 \nodepart{three} 6]
    ]
    [6\nodepart{two} 7 \nodepart{three} 8 \nodepart{four} 9 \nodepart{five} 1
      \nodepart{six} 7,fit=band 
       [6\nodepart{two} 7 \nodepart{three} 8 
            [6]
            [7\nodepart{two} 8
                [7]
                [8]
            ]
       ]
       [9\nodepart{two} 1 \nodepart{three} 7
            [9]
            [1\nodepart{two} 7
                [1]
                [7]
            ]
       ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks, it looks good more than tikz, thanks for the suggestion, I will try it in my next report.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo, of course. The package is designed for drawing trees. And don't wait for next time. Use it now. For showed tree you already has image :-)

Comment: Yes I will do it :-D

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{bplus}=[rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split ignore empty parts,draw]
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[bplus]
        \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=70mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=30mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=30mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 4}=[sibling distance=30mm]
        \node[rectangle split parts=10] {2 \nodepart{two} 4 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 1 \nodepart{five} 6 
        \nodepart{six} 7 \nodepart{seven} 8 \nodepart{eight} 9 \nodepart{nine} 1 \nodepart{ten} 7} [->]
        child {node[rectangle split parts=5] {2 \nodepart{two} 4 \nodepart{three} 3 \nodepart{four} 1 \nodepart{five} 6 }
            child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {2 \nodepart{two} 4}}
            child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {3 \nodepart{two} 1 \nodepart{three} 6}}
        } 
        child {node[rectangle split parts=6] {6 \nodepart{two} 7 \nodepart{three} 8 \nodepart{four} 9 \nodepart{five} 1 \nodepart{six} 7}
            child[sibling distance=25mm]{node {6 \nodepart{two} 7 \nodepart{three} 8}
            child[sibling distance=10mm]{node {6}}
            child[sibling distance=10mm]{node {7 \nodepart{two} 8}
                child[sibling distance=16mm]{node {7}}
                child[sibling distance=16mm]{node {8}}
            }
            }
            child[sibling distance=25mm] {node {9 \nodepart{two} 1 \nodepart{three} 7}
                child[sibling distance=20mm]{node {9}}
                child[sibling distance=20mm]{node {1 \nodepart{two} 7}
                    child[sibling distance=15mm]{node {1}}
                    child[sibling distance=15mm]{node {7}}
                }
            }
        }
        ;\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, and for me, can you add a couple of comment about the problem and how you solved it? I don't want to make another post the next time for the same problem :-D

Comment: wherever there is an overlap please experiment with the `sibling distance` which is nothing more than the distance between neighboring entries/ nodes