# Problem with rectangle split part fill and rectangle split ignore empty parts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am experiencing unexpected behavior in the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=3,
        rectangle split part fill={red!20,blue!20,yellow!80!red!20},
        rectangle split ignore empty parts](top){%
            Box 1
            \nodepart{two}Box 2
            \nodepart{three}\parbox{2in}{Box 3 which really can contain a lot of text just to see what is going on here}};
    \node[below=1em of top,
        draw,rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=3,
        rectangle split part fill={red!20,blue!20,yellow!80!red!20},
        rectangle split ignore empty parts]{%
            Box 1
            \nodepart{three}\parbox{2in}{Box 3 which really can contain a lot of text just to see what is going on here}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

`nodepart{three}` is not being filled correctly when `nodepart{two}` is missing and, therefore, ignored. I have simplified the code -- the `\parbox` is necessary because of some complex requirements for the text in `nodepart{three}`.

A workaround?

## Update

My interest is why this does not work, when, to all appearances, it ought to. The blue indicates necessary bits that are required; the yellow indicates what should be done. Occasionally there are no necessary bits, so the cell should not be shown -- but there will be explanatory text, indicated by the yellow background. TikZ would seem to be able to do this automatically, but there is a problem I have indicated. My apologies if this was not sufficiently clear.

I require TikZ for a variety of reasons, and am not really looking for alternative solutions. I played around with various tabulars, but the results were unsatisfactory.

[image: split node fill issue exx.]

## A workaround

Not an answer to my question, but lets me get back to work...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=3,
        rectangle split part fill={red!20,blue!20,none},
        rectangle split ignore empty parts] (X) {%
            Box 1
            \nodepart{three}\parbox{2in}{Box 3 which really can contain a lot of text just to see what is going on here}};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw[fill=yellow!80!red!20] (X.north west) rectangle (X.south east);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: workaround]

Comment: Do you really need tikz to obtain such a table?

Comment: Without some sort of background, your remark is not really useful. In any event, I can see no obvious reason why this should not work, and so I posed the question. So, to answer your question, yes, I 'need to obtain such a table,' and TikZ presents the most efficient method, to my mind, to achieve this.

Comment: Another `rectangle split` issue. The previous one was https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606256/tikz-rectangle-split-and-ignoring-empty-parts-problem.

Comment: I do seem to stumble upon them for some reason... ;>) no doubt because I use them quite a bit...

Comment: Reported to pgf-tikz here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1046

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Using `tblr` from `tabularray` would be a lot easier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={p{7cm}}, 
            hlines, vlines, 
            row{1-Y}={halign=c},
            row{1}={bg=red!20}, 
            row{2-Y}={bg=blue!20},
            row{Z}={bg=yellow!80!red!20}}
Box 1 \\
Box 2 \\
Box 3 which really can contain a lot of text just to see what is going on here
\end{tblr}
\medskip

\begin{tblr}{colspec={p{7cm}}, 
            hlines, vlines, 
            row{1-Y}={halign=c},
            row{1}={bg=red!20}, 
            row{2-Y}={bg=blue!20},
            row{Z}={bg=yellow!80!red!20}}
Box 1 \\
Box 3 which really can contain a lot of text just to see what is going on here
\end{tblr}
\medskip


\begin{tblr}{colspec={p{7cm}}, 
            hlines, vlines, 
            row{1-Y}={halign=c},
            row{1}={bg=red!20}, 
            row{2-Y}={bg=blue!20},
            row{Z}={bg=yellow!80!red!20}}
Box 1 \\
Box 2 \\
Box 2 \\
Box 2 \\
Box 3 which really can contain a lot of text just to see what is going on here
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this helps. When text for box two is missing, the cell remains. The colors are important and convey visual significance. The blue indicates necessary bits that are required; the yellow indicates what should be done. Occasionally there are no necessary bits, so the cell should not be shown -- but there will be explanatory text, indicated by the yellow background. TikZ would seem to be able to do this automatically, but there is a problem I have indicated

Comment: @sgmoye: This background information would have been useful to know before. I have updated my answer accordingly.